# Passing raw PCM data to the Superpowered SDK

Tags: android, pcm, superpowered

In my app I receive arrays of shorts containing PCM data. I would like to pass this data to the Superpowered SDK in order to change the speed, seek etc. However, there does not appear to be an official method within Superpowered to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to manipulate that data after you received them all, then just create a WAV file with those and use the SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.

If you need to manipulate that data while you are receiving them "live", use SuperpoweredTimeStretching and SuperpoweredResampler for speed changes. Seeking is simple, since you have the data in memory.

Comment: Ok, Thanks very much!